# How can I avoid the Console while doing GUI with C?

Tags: c, user-interface, codeblocks

Okay this is the sample code

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "A threat has been detected by Windows!!", "Warning!!", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

But whenever I compile this. It gives me a Message Box as ecpected but what I get more is the Command Prompt with it. I just don't want that ugly thing how can I modify or compile my code to get only the GUI ? I am using Code::Blocks IDE.

Comment: Why are you a programmer who calls a console an ugly thing? It's not an ugly thing it's a useful thing, certainly not as much on windows, but it's useful. So, you don't want the console to show up, search for the related code blocks settings.

Comment: @iharob am not calling the independent Console ugly only in this case I am saying so. And even if i execute the program directly from the build place the console still shows up !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to Code Blocks IDE, you have to change the type application in your project.

From the project properties, tab Build Targets, change the type console application to GUI application.

Check: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=12007.0

Comment: LOL I don't know why this answer is actually downvoted !! But this my friend helped to solve my silly problem. Thank You.

Comment: @DisortedCasanøva you should then accept it... Downvotes don't necessarily mean that the answer is wrong, it's just not following the principles of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @iharob Hmm thats okay !!